# How and where to execute code for "clearing Jupyter Notebooks Output in All Cells"

Tags: jupyter-notebook, output, infinite-loop, large-files

I have created an infinte loop and now my jupyter notebook is stuck.

I have found a solution in this article:

[https://saturncloud.io/blog/how-to-clear-jupyter-notebooks-output-in-all-cells-from-the-linux-terminal/#:~:text=By%20executing%20the%20command%20jupyter,cells%20from%20the%20Linux%20terminal](https://saturncloud.io/blog/how-to-clear-jupyter-notebooks-output-in-all-cells-from-the-linux-terminal/#:%7E:text=By%20executing%20the%20command%20jupyter,cells%20from%20the%20Linux%20terminal).

*"All you need to do is navigate to the directory containing the notebook and execute the following command:"*

$ jupyter nbconvert --ClearOutputPreprocessor.enabled=True --inplace notebook.ipynb

Where should i run this code and how exactly?

Note: Please explain for very beginner

Tried running it on different terminals, but couldnt find where i should run this code